# Is there a wildcard for intergers to use in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to know if there is a way to check if a string contains a certain pattern for a regex.

For example:

`string.matches("something[0-9]x")` would check if the string contains a substring of "something" with any single digit integer following it followed by "x". But lets say if I want to check the same thing, but there is no limit for that int, ie it could be 1000000. Is there like a wildcard for an int that I can use?

Comment: It's time to read about the things you are using. This question is really much better served by a trip to the help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use modifier `+` after your character class which match the preceding token one or more time :

```
string.matches("something[0-9]+x")
```

Comment: [tag:regex-as-a-service]

Comment: I would tend to go for `++` to prevent backtracking in the case of almost-matches - for example if the file is big and contains many things that almost match but don't end in `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions work on characters; they have no semantic understanding of those characters.  So it doesn't make sense to talk about "integers" here; the best that you can do is to talk about "digits".  The number "1" is one digit; "1234" is four.

In a regular expression, you can match one or more of the preceding pattern using "+", so the regex `"something[0-9]+x"` should do what you want.  If you want an upper bound on the number of digits, than you can try something like `"something[0-9]{1,5}x"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply use *, so in your example `string.matches("something[0-9]+x")`

It would match a string something followed by any digit from 0 to 9, which have to occur at least one time, so * means zero or more times, while + means it have to occur at least one time but can occur more times if it wants.

If you do [0-9]{n,m} you can specify with m and n in which range it can occur for example:

`[0-9]{2,3}` will match any digit and it have to occur 2 or 3 times, if you only use one digit in this bracs `[0-9]{2}` it has to occur at least 2 times.

But at last: simply learn to use google ... there are so many regexp sites with tutorials and stuff.

Comment: `*` is incorrect - it must be `+` to match the spec. `*` will obviously match `somethingx` and that is not the intent of the OP.